# Match dictionary keys to existing csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm a little lost with this problem. Heres what I did.

First:

I created a dictionary that set the ID as the key and the other information as the values from a csv file (File A).

```
import csv
A_ID = {}

'''This makes the File A dictionary'''
with open("file_A.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    A_ID = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in reader}
```

Output:

```
'35': ['1', 'Florida Ave', 'Tampa']
```

Now I have another file (File B) that I need to look up its ID and match it with file A's ID from the dictionary I just created. Then add in the values of the dictionary into File B as a new column.
Here's what I have so far:

```
'''Create the loop that matches dictionary keys to ID in file B'''
with open("file_B", 'r') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(output)
    for row in reader:
        if row[2] = A_ID:
            print(row[2])
```

Error Returned:

```
File ".\mb_active.py", line 15
if row[3] = active_id:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected outcome:

```
State, ID, Car,  Address,  Street,      City
FL,    35, Chevy,  1,    Florida Ave,  Tampa
```

Address, Street, City are the values from A_ID dictionary. Everything else is from file B. I can't use pandas and I have to keep file A's dictionary for later usage. If pandas is the only way to achieve this goal that is ok but explain why? Also, if you guys have any tips on how to learn python on your own please share! <3

Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: `=` should be `==`, where the error is pointing to with the `^`

Comment: it would be more clear if you added samples of both csv files. at least to know which column represents what.

Comment: for your comment about pandas - pandas makes things easier for this type of work. If you are going to be doing this type of work often, try to learn pandas. It will make your life easier (and faster)

Comment: My boss told me not to use pandas because it won't later on. Is pandas the only way to solve this problem? I'm asking...is my boss wrong? @MattR

Comment: @beary93,  pandas is not the *only* way to solve this, but it is my preferred way. on a side note... look at [the most popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) and type in pandas. there's a reason why there are 80 pandas questions out of 761 python questions today (at time of writing this). that's 10%! It's a very popular tool in any data analysts belt. Boss may not be wrong based on your type of work, but I use pandas every single day at my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

apart from the syntax error, your implementation is wrong. `row[2]` is an id, so you should ask `A_ID` the corresponding entry. Something like this could work

```
a_row = A_ID.get(row[2], None)
if a_row:
    print(row + a_row)
```